# using scoped css in php included files

Tags: php, css

I always wanted to write css code inside or near the corresponding DOM element.
Mostly because of easier handling with php included pages.
And I was always prevented in this by various arguments, like slow browser rendering etc.
Is this now maybe allowed using css scope attribute, without losing performances?

For example:

```
menutop.php
<div id="menutop">
    <style scoped>
    // styles for entire menutop.php
    </style>
</div>

content.php
<div id="content">
    <style scoped>
    // styles for entire content.php
    </style>
</div>
```

Comment: Scoping styles doesn't change any of those arguments, you could achieve the same thing using class names. The only thing you do is give up browser support.

Comment: @Nit, Do you allow a possibility that browsers would not accept scoped css if it would make them slow. Maybe there is some new rendering algorithm, which doesn't care where is placed css code ?

Comment: You misunderstand the issues you've described. Scoping CSS isn't what makes it slow, you can already scope CSS using classes, IDs and other selectors.

Comment: @Nit, I would say that I understand the issue very well . Of course, I can simulate scope attribute adding new classes, but the price is slow rendering. But, what if browsers accepted scoped css JUST BECAUSE of new algorithm which will still make rendering slowly IN CASE of new classes inside html, AND NOT in case of new css (scoped) code inside html.

Comment: bonaca are you refering to download speed rather than render speed of the browser?

Comment: @David, AFAIK main download time is spent for browser request and server response and this is made per file, not per code in files. Why do you think  download time is relevant here?

Comment: because render time is negligible really for most css rules - specific/ scoped/inline or not and i've never heard of anyone questioning render time for css not for the puny amount of data involved...modern processors nail it. Really scoping has fallen from the radar as there is no need for inline style blocks that only effect the parent, specific rules can be used to achieve this.

Comment: @David, using scoped css I don't want to achieve faster page processing My reason is about easier handling with css code blocks. Searching a large css file is time consuming compared to have css code inside the corresponding DOM element. So, regarding the essence of css rule, there is no need for scoped css, but regarding to easier organizing large number of files and its css rules, scoped css IS needed. But only in case if scoped css does not make page processing slow. And I hope this is the case, because in contrary maybe browsers would not accepted them.

Comment: well look you have your opinion and its not wrong although unsupported by ie and chrome. But if you ever try load testing to scale a website and want an efficient cost structure, this is where such a approach would be unwise. Think about it the visitor lands on your website, downloads the css files/ js files, when they visit the next page, these files are cached and served locally, therefore costing you 0 in bandwidth.